# How to fetch records from temporary table created in C#.net form

Tags: asp.net

i have created a temporary datatable in my C# Form to assign data to that table from excel sheet.Now i want to get one particular row from that table to check some conditions in my form, later i have to store this data from the temp table in to sql server table.
can any one Help me to insert and get record from the temp table.

creating temp table like:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable("Dynamically_Generated");

dt.Columns.Add("OderNbr", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("CHOL2", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("HDLC3", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("TRIGL", typeof(string));
```

Comment: Temp-Table does not mean in SQL-Server but in memory as Datatable? Have you read some of the available tutorials about `DataAdapters`? For example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/33y2221y(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: This Data Table created as temporary table in My application not in SQL Sever, i want All insert and fetch records transactions will do on this table. at last i need to insert this table into sql server table.

Answer (score 0):

First fetch what row you want from temp table and then insert it into the sql server table
Apply logic wherever you want

Follow this link

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/212006/Connecting-Windows-Form-Application-With-ADO-NET-i

Comment: Kaushik,you misunderstand my question, i want fetch record from my temp table that created in my application(C#). After done All necessary transactions i need to insert my temp table data into sql table.